# Calculate the fractions (of male and female passengers who survived from 1st, 2nd and 3rd class

Tags: r

I'm unsure of how to complete my homework task, where I have to group male and females depending on the class they are from in order to find the percentage of which survived from each class based.

This is a small sample of the data within the text file being used.

```
1=alive
0=dead

Name                                            PClass Age  Sex     Survived

"Allen, Miss Elisabeth Walton"                  1st    29   female  1

"Allison, Miss Helen Loraine"                   1st     2   female  0

"Allison, Mr Hudson Joshua Creighton"           1st    30   male    0

"Allison, Mrs Hudson JC (Bessie Waldo Daniels)" 1st    25   female  0

"Allison, Master Hudson Trevor"                 1st    0.92 male    1

"Anderson, Mr Harry"                            1st    47   male    1

"Andrews, Miss Kornelia Theodosia"              1st    63   female  1

"Andrews, Mr Thomas, jr"                        1st    39   male    0

"Appleton, Mrs Edward Dale (Charlotte Lamson)"  1st    58   female  1

"Artagaveytia, Mr Ramon"                        1st    71   male    0

"Astor, Colonel John Jacob"                     1st    47   male    0
```

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried already? Also, in order for us to test the code, please provide a sample of your data, posting the output of `dput(head(data, 20))`

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the `dplyr` library:

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  group_by(PClass, Sex) %>%
  summarize(ratio = sum(Survived) / n())
```

(untested code, sorry)

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of doing this. Assuming DT is your [data.table](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.html), one option is to use the aggregate function:

```
aggregate(DT$Survived, by=list(DT$PClass, DT$Sex))
```

Take a look at the [documentation for aggregate](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.0/topics/aggregate) to see what the parameters mean.

Another possibility is to import the data.table library and then group by the desired columns:

```
library(data.table)
DT[,list(mean_survival = mean(Survived)),by=.(PClass, Sex)]
```